# Add navigation dots to my jquery product slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, slideshow

I'm working on a slideshow right now, but can't figure out how I can get some navigation dots ("ol li") to work with my code. The problem is: I need to know the current element in the "li" tags (dynamically)

It should be something like:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

I'm also not sure if the

```
<ol>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    ...
<ol>
```

is a good idea and how to add the list elements dynamically while the elements are growing.

But, yet the slideshow works very good. Only the navigation dots are the problem.

Here is the jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ad2qmvb/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i took a look at your code and the solution was pretty simple. after the click on the li's u didn't update sliderint and slidernext with the correct index, i changed that and your fiddle started working. 
old:

```
sliderInt = sliderNext;
sliderNext = sliderNext+1;
```

new:

```
  sliderInt = index;
  sliderNext = index +1;
```

- working fiddle:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ad2qmvb/15/)